# Must I initialize other folders/directories which are in my master repository?

Tags: git

A few days back I started to learn about git, so I am very much a beginner for git and I never used any kind of version control before it.

What exactly I want to do is that —— want to use git for tracking my project local (offline).
For this, I made my main folder/directory called "project" and by using `git init`, I initialized it as a git repository. Now in the `project` directory, I made 3 sub-directories or folders called

```
Design
Css
Images
```

Will I have to initialize other folders/directories which are in my master repository?

Any suggestion also for tracking my project local (offline) will be helpful for me?

Comment: You don't need to run `git init` in the sub-directories.  You will simply need to `git add` files in those sub-directories.

Comment: Please note: 'master' is a branch, not a repository. About working offline/online: a lot of people are using Github (Private or public) for their projects. But there are many options where you can host a git repo.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the following tutorials:

- [Introduction to Git by Github](http://learn.github.com/p/intro.html)
- [Pro Git, the free online version](http://git-scm.com/book)

To answer your question briefly: no you only have to run `git init` once per repository. Afterwards you mark the folder and files you wanna track by adding them using `git add`. But there is much more to it and I really recommend to work through a tutorial before you continue!

Answer (score 0):

Once you initialize a git repo inside a folder(which you mean master repo), any files or folders created inside it will automatically be tracked and no further git initialization is required for this. Just keep adding them using

```
 git add <filename>
```

and when you run

```
 git status
```

,those files will be displayed as being tracked. Still you need to learn more to have basic understanding.

You can refer the tutorials suggest by reto above, those will surely help.

Answer (score 0):

git does not track empty folders.

Check this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) if you want an workaround.

Comment: Git will track anything only when asked for i.e, git add, the ans is misleading

Comment: plz, tell me how to do it instead... I just tried. `mkdir foo;cd foo;git init;mkdir foo; git add foo; git commit -a` and git says nothing to commit. I think your comment is misleading.